# Set acceptable domains for generated passwords

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, passwords, microsoft-edge

Since some time ago, browsers will allow users to generate a secure password for the application, they are using.
This seems like a nice feature, but can have unwanted side effects, like the users cannot know his password, if prompted on another domain.

Is there a way to control, for which pages the generated password might be suitable?
Is there a way to tell the browser, that he's seeing a password reset or change for a specific domain?

Essentially, I'd like to allow the browser to autofill at login.contoso.com, when I originally set the password at account.contoso.com.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in Edge/Chrome, if you want to autofill the password for a specific domain, you can "Add password" in password manager.

**Edge: Settings --> Passwords --> Add password**

**Chrome: Settings --> Autofill --> Add**

Also, if you have saved password in a subdomain like account.contoso.com, you will have an "autofill" dropdown menu (click the box to call) in another subdomain like login.contoso.com. Though it is not the exact "autofill".

Comment: Well - that's the users way to do so, but i'd like to control it via html.